# Rails 3.1, rspec, guard and spork is really slow on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am trying to be a better tester. Having so much problems with the set up that I wonder if it's worth it.

Can somebody please help?

I am running Rails 3.1, rspec, guard capybara and spork on a windows box. I use the guard-spork gem. This what I get when I run bundle exec guard

Look at the line "Finished in 421.87 seconds". Thats one test!

I see I get an error with guard-spork complaining about no fork support (Windows problem), but later this line "./magazine_slave.rb:22:in `run'", should indicate that magazine_slave runs (Windows runs spork with magazine instead of fork).

Any Ideas?

```
Guard is now watching at 'c:/Users/Andreas/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 workspace/maktaba'
'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Starting Spork for Test::Unit & RSpec
ERROR: Guard::Spork failed to achieve its <start>, exception was:
NotImplementedError: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-spork-0.3.1/lib/guard/spork/runner.rb:40:in `fork'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-spork-0.3.1/lib/guard/spork/runner.rb:40:in `spawn_child'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-spork-0.3.1/lib/guard/spork/runner.rb:23:in `launch_sporks'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-spork-0.3.1/lib/guard/spork.rb:17:in `start'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:322:in `send'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:322:in `run_supervised_task'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:320:in `catch'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:320:in `run_supervised_task'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:153:in `start'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:254:in `run_on_guards'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:253:in `each'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:253:in `run_on_guards'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:252:in `catch'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:252:in `run_on_guards'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:251:in `each'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:251:in `run_on_guards'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard.rb:152:in `start'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/lib/guard/cli.rb:68:in `start'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/guard-0.8.8/bin/guard:6
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/guard:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/guard:19

Guard::Spork has just been fired
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
F

Failures:

  1) UserCruds Creates a new user
 Failure/Error: click_button "Submit"
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
   You might have expected an instance of Array.
   The error occurred while evaluating nil.map
 # ./app/views/users/_form.html.erb:38:in `_app_views_users__form_html_erb___24339687_119563452'
 # ./app/views/users/_form.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users__form_html_erb___24339687_119563452'
 # ./app/views/users/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___963176717_119608284'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:47:in `create'
 # (eval):2:in `send'
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/user_cruds_spec.rb:16
 # ./magazine_slave.rb:22:in `run'
 # magazine_slave_provider.rb:17

Finished in 421.87 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Comment: New record! "Finished in 1288.48 seconds"

Comment: It actually takes that long or is it the timer bug? Rspec changed the way it times runs, spork to my knowledge hasn't adapted yet

Comment: I have not timed it, but it's not far from the realtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because rspec loads the rails environment, it's slow. The more gems you have the slower it gets

Thats why spork is a great tool. It loads the rails environment and guard can look for the changes without reloading the rails environment. But there is a bug in the guard-spork gem. It does not work with windows because it depends on fork. Even tough spork do not use fork on windows guard-spork does. Fork is not supported on non-UNIX systems.

I researched the problem and ended up with a different aproach. I facture out the logic to the lib folder and do not include the spec_helper file in the specs. Then rails does not get loaded, only the spesific test logic. This is fast and force me to write more readable code.

Check out this [video](http://www.kensodev.com/2012/05/09/corey-haines-fast-rails-tests/) on a talk  by Cory Haines, for more on the subject.